# ListView items disappear in designer after adding WrapGrid

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

WrapGrid makes the TextBlocks effectively disappear.  The outline of the item is shown, but the text cannot be seen.  During runtime the items appear correctly.

How to make them appear during design time?

```
 <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"></WrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.Items>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>LOREM IPSUM</TextBlock>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Is there any style applied to `TextBlock` `Foreground` property?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [The content of a ListView with ItemsPanel modified is not shown in designer (VS and Blend)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25993352/4133418).

Basically it's a known bug, they suggest use ItemsWrapGrid instead of WrapGrid.

Comment: I wish all bugs could as easily be fixed by adding five characters